# How to know that other person have saved my phone number?

Tags: android-contacts, whatsapp

This is in scenario such as if want to whatsapp anyone and i wanted to know whether other person have saved my number then what I should do?

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. You can view that person's profile if you have saved their number.